# How do I import constants from my settings.py file into my Django console?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, console, constants

I'm using Python 3.7 with Django.  I have this at the end of my settings.py file

```
MAX_AGE_IN_HOURS = 18
```

When I fire up my console, how do I get this constant recognized?  I have tried teh below, but get an error complaining that the above is not defined.

```
from django.conf import settings
(age.seconds / 3600) > MAX_AGE_IN_HOURS
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'MAX_AGE_IN_HOURS' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is standard Python semantics; you imported `settings`, so you need to access the values via that name.

```
(age.seconds / 3600) > settings.MAX_AGE_IN_HOURS
```